.NET 7 API Middleware Mask
I am developing an API with .net 7. My question is, can we mask the parameters coming to all ends in the API in the middleware?
For example
public async Task<ApiOperationResult<Token>> Login(LoginRequestMobile userLogin)

This is the beginning of a login method. When I debug the starting point and examine the userLogin, I can clearly see the entered inputs. For example
PhoneNumber="+905555555555"
Password = "Taha123.."
But what I want to see
PhoneNumber="******"
Password = "******"
Of course, since I will be making a query with these parameters, this should only be visible. They must be automatically decrypted when querying.
In short, even the developer should not be able to see some sensitive information in debug. Sorry if the question is a bit strange, but can we do something like this?
I tried encryption at the middleware layer, but I could not access my API.

Whatever you have in memory can be "seen" in one way or another, regardless how much effort you put in "masking". In case of passwords that's mitigated by making seeing it useless to a potential attacker. For other data that cannot be hashed or similiarly made useless to see, there are methods to mask in logs. The debugger, though is a different beast.

You could use encryption in order to keep your sensitive data secure but developer wouldn't be able to see it  doesn't make any sense, If  they want they can, its not about your scenario, its everywhere. In big tech companies as well, even you hash the password but it still can be seen if the developer want.

You could consider using symmetric encryption algorithms like AES. You could also combine the UserId along with the property need to encrypted, so that It will add additional security layer.

^^ But again: That would serve you nothing. Your Devs have access to everything they need to decrypt that data if they so absolutely wished to see it.
